# Error logging into my website with Facebook "Can not Load URL"

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth

I have a problem when logging in with the Facebook API from my website, the first time you log in everything works fine, but when you log in for the second time, you get the following error message *"Can not Load URL : The domain of this URL is not included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."*

I already made the correct configuration of my Apps in Facebook Developer, then I share the code of the connection file:

```html
<?php

if (isset($_GET['code']) || strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],'facebook') !== false) {
 require_once("../includes/core.php");
 require_once("../social/Facebook/autoload.php");

 } else {

 require_once("assets/includes/core.php");
 require_once("assets/social/Facebook/autoload.php");
}

if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => siteConfig('fb_app_id'),
  'app_secret' => siteConfig('fb_app_secret'),
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',

  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
define('APP_URL','https://www.ciines.com/assets/sources/fbconnect.php');
$permissions = [];
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];

try {
 $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
 $request = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,gender', $accessToken);
 $graphNode = $request->getGraphNode();  
 $location = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));  
   $fbid = $graphNode['id'];         
 $name = $graphNode['name']; 
 $email = $graphNode['email'];  
 $gender = $graphNode['gender'];  
 fbconnect($fbid,$name,$email,$gender,$location);
 header("Location: ".$sm['config']['site_url']);  

} else {

 $permissions = ['email']; // optional
 $callback = $sm['config']['site_url'].'assets/sources/fbconnect.php';
 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback,$permissions);

 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);

}

?>
```

Comment: In which step of the process do you get that error, when you send the user to the login dialog, or after they are redirected back to your app? Those two logins happen from the exact same starting point, not different URLs?

Comment: When the user enters a second time, the error originates

Comment: Fix it, just update the Facebook SDK (Folder called Facebook)